# Improving search presence with micro blogs on keyworded domain names

Tags: seo, links, keywords, blog, link-building

A client of mine asked me to optimize his main website's search presence. One of my colleagues who has some previous experience in SEO told me that apart from the "normal" things to optimize on the main website (semantic html, content-html ratio, relevant meta tags, relevant headings, etc) it's also a very good idea to buy keyworded domain names and add SEO optimized Wordpress blogs to those with relevant, regular blog posts and links to the main site.

Here's an example of what he told me:

Suppose you have SmartTvGuy.com as your TV repair website. You buy 10 keyworded domain names, such as: televisionrepair.com, television-repair.com, tv-repair.com, tv-repair.net, repair-television.com, broken-television.com etc. Then you install Wordpress on these one-by-one, one or two every week with 100% relevant *keyworded* content and relevant links to smarttvguy.com. After one blog like this is finished, you wait at least a month so Google has time to index it. After a site has been indexed, start to write regular keyworded blog posts. Like one post every week or two. He also said that duplicated content is a big no-no.

Apart from these, he also said that I should put only maximum 3 of these blogs on one IP address (one server).

My questions would be that is this a good technique?

Comment: You have two perfectly valid and different points on why this is a bad idea. Go back to your friend and please explain what you have learned. That way, you will be correcting at least a small portion of the bad SEO advice/parroting that is out there that hurts good people like you. Imagine had you followed this advice without coming here first? You would have caused a lot for damage for your client and your reputation. This is important stuff. I am glad you came here first and invite you to ask these questions as often as you like. That way, we can guide you down the right path. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a false premise. Here is what I mean.

You have one website and 10 new websites. You have now divided your attention and efforts by 11 and created 10 more competitors. It is that simple.

The notion of a keyword match domain name by Google was a misnomer. Sure it existed for a while, but it was a silly notion right from the start and Google realized it's mistake quickly but somewhat reluctantly and the idea has been dead for years now.

Blogs are great. But they require constant work. You cannot just create them and then leave them. Your premise is to increase the number of sites to maintain by 11. Any site that becomes stagnant fails. You will have to keep all these new sites fresh and relevant. That is a lot of work. As well, you will have 10 new sites with no value to pass to the main site.

It is always better to put your efforts into your one website instead of dividing the effort. It is always better to focus on one killer site than create several at best mediocre sites.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy. This is a link scheme and is definitely something the search engines hate. Doing it will ultimately hurt your site. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably fit the prototypical of `Doorway Pages` and link schemes like this are exactly what Google are targeting to improve search quality.

See this question: [What are doorway pages and how can they hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78250/what-are-doorway-pages-and-how-can-they-hurt-seo/78257#78257)

So how example can one create single-purpose microsite to attract links and funnel authority to your main website you would need to be more strategic than this.

Take `rainycafe.com`: Simple, one page website that can play ambient cafe and rain audio. This is a link building (and sales funnel) website for the Chicago agency Ethercycle.

If you want to be useful, clever, insightful or amusing then break away from your commercial intent and think broader. Here are some examples:

- `Should I replace or repair my TV`: Single page microsite that outlines scenarios on whether you should or shouldn't repair your tv and when you should get a replacement.
- `Why does my tv break`: Showcases the individual parts of a tv, why they break and how they get repaired.

The pupose of creating microsites is that they are great `linkable assets` and if you are performing an SEO strategy for your friend you need to think of the accrued traffic benefit.

The main goal of these websites is to be shared or linked to, so that should be their primary call to action.

Doing it so deliberately like you are proposing is far less valuable than simply creating content for your website - so save yourself the domain registration fee.